# Show default date on "Input Type Date" in Razor Page, ASP.NET Core 6.0 web app

Tags: date, input, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a Index page and link to the Search page. I want when running the page Search to display today's default date as "16/11/2023", but when selecting another date like "15/11/2023" and pressing the "Search" button, the results will be displayed and loaded return to the page, the selected date will be “15/11/2023”, not the default date “16/11/2023”.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7tnu.png

Code in file Search.cshtml

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Date</label></td>
        <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="" /></td>
        <td><button type="submit" id="btnSearch" asp-page-handler="Data">Search</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialLoad = true;
    if (initialLoad) {
        // Do work that is done when the page was first loaded.
        document.getElementById('date').value = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    } else {
        // Do work when it's not the initial load.
    }
</script>
```

Code in Search.cshtml.cs

```
public void OnPostData()
{
    string str_date = Request.Form["date"];
    // Code show result search
}
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> I want when running the page Search to display today's default date as
> "16/11/2023", but when selecting another date like "15/11/2023" and
> pressing the "Search" button, the results will be displayed and loaded
> return to the page, the selected date will be “15/11/2023”, not the
> default date “16/11/2023”

You can use the ViewData to display the date in a Razor page and set its value to the current date or the selected date by default, Since the page has already fetched the date and displayed it on the page, you don't need to set a default date in the OnGet method. Then you can use [BindProperty] to automatically bind the form field to the Date property, and then use ViewData to set the selecteddate to the value of the Date property, You can use the following code as a reference:

Controller:

```
[BindProperty]
public string Date { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
     ViewData["SelectedDate"] = this.Date;
     return Page();
}
```

Page:

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Date</label></td>
            <td><input type="date" id="date" name="date" value="@((string)ViewData["SelectedDate"] ?? DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))" /></td>
            <td><button type="submit">search</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Default date:

[image]

After I choose date and search:

[image]

Comment: Thank Yuning Duan very much.